# Replace Gfci plug with standard

Tags: cord-and-plug

I need to use a timer for my pool filter but the filter plug is a  Gfci so it won't turn on automatically. Can I replace the plug with a standard plug?

Comment: The manufacturer has obviously decided that use of a GFCI is prudent. It's your device though, so sure, you can replace the plug with a more basic one. If you do this, I would recommend you also replace the outlet with a GFCI outlet, so you still have protection against ground faults.

Comment: I agree with @CactusCake.  Code usually dictates GFCIs within 6 feet of a water source, but for a hot tub I would go the extra mile and use GFCI because of the presence of water at the pump.  Meanwhile, using a GFCI generally will not impede electricity unless it trips due to an actual ground fault.  Please clarify in your question whether this is the problem you're having.

Comment: My reading, which the OP should confirm, is that the GFCI plug automatically trips when power is cut, preventing its effective use with a timer.

Answer (score 2):

Does the cord/plug-mounted GFCI *really* trip every time power fails?  Or are you assuming it will because other GFCIs do?  That is a design choice by the GFCI manufacture, and that would be a *rather stupid* design choice for a cord-mounted GFCI. For this very reason.

### Change the order of things

Right now the sequence is:

1. Breaker panel
2. Place you would like to put the timer
3. GFCI

Change the order so the GFCI is before the timer.

Since this appears to be an appliance with a GFCI integrated into its power cord, this gives you three ways to do this, in order of increasing badness:

- replace the appliance power cord with a better GFCI cord which does not trip when the power is cut.
- Hack the appliance to include a timer.
- use a GFCI upstream of the receptacle, and then replace the appliance's power cord with one that is not GFCI.

Your insurance company will not like the last two.

Answer (score 0):

We have a hair dryer which has what looks like a GFCI plug. This plug does not trip when power to it  is interrupted. The GFCI receptacle in my garage does not trip when I cycle the breaker to that circuit. The two GFCI breakers  in my panel do not trip when there is an interruption to the incoming power. What is all this talk about GFCIs tripping when the power goes off and comes back on?

Try the GFCI plug to the pool filter and see how it performs when the power is cycled off and then back on.